# Javascript: Quiz program: Doesn't load the second question

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning javascript and writing a Quiz program as part of learning process.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>          
        <head>  
                <meta charset="UTF-8">                                              
        </head> 
        <body>  
                <form type="submit" onsubmit = "populateQuestion()">                
                        <h2 id="question">Question goes here</h2>                   
                        <input name = "option" type="radio" value="A"><span id = "choiceA">First option here</span><br/>
                        <input name = "option" type="radio" value="B"><span id = "choiceB">Second option here</span><br/>
                        <input name = "option" type="radio" value="C"><span id = "choiceC">Third option here</span><br/>
                        <input name = "option" type="radio" value="D"><span id = "choiceD">Fourth option here</span><br/>
                        <button type = "submit">Submit</button>                     
                </form>                       
        </body>                                                                     

<script>
var question = document.getElementById("question");
var choiceA = document.getElementById("choiceA");
var choiceB = document.getElementById("choiceB");
var choiceC = document.getElementById("choiceC");
var choiceD = document.getElementById("choiceD");

var quesIndex = 0;
var defQuestions = [
        {
                question : "Q01?",
                choiceA : "A1",
                choiceB : "B1",
                choiceC : "C1",
                choiceD : "D1",
                answer : "A"
        },
        {
                question : "Q02?",
                choiceA : "A2",
                choiceB : "B2",
                choiceC : "C2",
                choiceD : "D2",
                answer : "A"

        },
        {
                question : "Q03?",
                choiceA : "A3",
                choiceB : "B3",
                choiceC : "C3",
                choiceD : "D3",
                answer : "B"

        },
        {
                question : "Q04?",
                choiceA : "A4",
                choiceB : "B4",
                choiceC : "C4",
                choiceD : "D4",
                answer : "B"

        }
];

function renderQuestion() {
        question.innerHTML = defQuestions[quesIndex].question;
        choiceA.innerHTML = defQuestions[quesIndex].choiceA;
        choiceB.innerHTML = defQuestions[quesIndex].choiceB;
        choiceC.innerHTML = defQuestions[quesIndex].choiceC;
        choiceD.innerHTML = defQuestions[quesIndex].choiceD;
}

function populateQuestion() {
        console.log(quesIndex);
        renderQuestion();
        quesIndex += 1;
}

populateQuestion();
</script>
</html>
```

When I load the page, `populateQuestion()` executed and loaded the default question and options (the first element of defQuestions array). This part is working fine.

[image]

When I click on `Submit` button, the next question supposed to be loaded. But the next question is not loading.

The `console.log(quesIndex);` prints only `0` and then the console window logs clearing.

Is there anything wrong in the implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you intend to process the form submission but your current implementation will submit the form thus causing the page to reload and you script to be reset.

You should add an event listener to capture for the form submission event and process it yourself (I expect you'll store the users given answers in an array)

```js
var question = document.getElementById("question");
var choiceA = document.getElementById("choiceA");
var choiceB = document.getElementById("choiceB");
var choiceC = document.getElementById("choiceC");
var choiceD = document.getElementById("choiceD");

var quesIndex = 0;
var defQuestions = [{
    question: "Q01?",
    choiceA: "A1",
    choiceB: "B1",
    choiceC: "C1",
    choiceD: "D1",
    answer: "A"
  },
  {
    question: "Q02?",
    choiceA: "A2",
    choiceB: "B2",
    choiceC: "C2",
    choiceD: "D2",
    answer: "A"

  },
  {
    question: "Q03?",
    choiceA: "A3",
    choiceB: "B3",
    choiceC: "C3",
    choiceD: "D3",
    answer: "B"

  },
  {
    question: "Q04?",
    choiceA: "A4",
    choiceB: "B4",
    choiceC: "C4",
    choiceD: "D4",
    answer: "B"

  }
];


var questionnaire = document.getElementById("questionnaire");

function renderQuestion() {
  question.innerHTML = defQuestions[quesIndex].question;
  choiceA.innerHTML = defQuestions[quesIndex].choiceA;
  choiceB.innerHTML = defQuestions[quesIndex].choiceB;
  choiceC.innerHTML = defQuestions[quesIndex].choiceC;
  choiceD.innerHTML = defQuestions[quesIndex].choiceD;
}

function populateQuestion() {
  console.log(quesIndex);
  renderQuestion();
  quesIndex += 1;
}

function onsubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent form from actually posting
  var a = questionnaire.querySelector('input[name = option]:checked'); 
  
  console.clear();
  console.log("Q:",quesIndex,"Answer:",a.value);
  a.checked=false;//deselect it ready for new question
  populateQuestion();
}

questionnaire.addEventListener('submit', onsubmit, false);


populateQuestion();
```

```css
form {
    margin-bottom:100px;/* just some space for the console log in the snippet*/
}
```

```html
<form id="questionnaire" type="submit">
  <h2 id="question">Question goes here</h2>
  <input name="option" type="radio" value="A"><span id="choiceA">First option here</span><br/>
  <input name="option" type="radio" value="B"><span id="choiceB">Second option here</span><br/>
  <input name="option" type="radio" value="C"><span id="choiceC">Third option here</span><br/>
  <input name="option" type="radio" value="D" required><span id="choiceD">Fourth option here</span><br/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The first question is not loading until I click on submit button. How do I load the first question user loads this page?

Comment: @NayabBashaSayed I don't understand. The first question is rendered on load as shown in the snippet.

Comment: But after the changes mentioned by you, it's not loading until I click on Submit button

Comment: @NayabBashaSayed It's working fine for me. Does the snippet not work for you?

Comment: No. It is not. https://hastebin.com/owagelopik.cs   It's not loading the first element of questions array.

Comment: You're telling me that your code posted elsewhere and not posted here is somehow not working!? My example works as you can clearly see. When you say 'its not working' its not at clear that what you meant is "Thanks, it works perfectly in your snippet but its not working for me in my implementation". I expect its not working in 'hastebin' (whatever that is) because the script tries to run before the elements exists. What's in the console? How do you get hastebin to work anyway, there's no UI - I don't see the code running at all.

Comment: Your snippet works good. I just couln't figure out how to load the first question on page load with my code. Sorry if I offend you.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the part `the script tries to run before the elements exists`. Could you please point me to some source where I can learn these.

Comment: The script needs to be run after the page has loaded. If your script is in the <head> then you'll need to call populateQuestion() on document ready (Google it). Alternatively you can put the whole script (or just <script>populateQuestion();</script>) at the bottom of the body.

Answer (score 2):

If you submit a form then it's reloading the Page and start again with the first question. Change this

`<form type="submit" onsubmit = "populateQuestion()">`
to
 <`form type="submit">`
and
 `<button type = "submit">Submit</button>`
to
 `<button type = "button" onclick="populateQuestion()">Submit</button>`

like  this:

```
        <form type="submit">                
                <h2 id="question">Question goes here</h2>                   
                <input name = "option" type="radio" value="A"><span id = "choiceA">First option here</span><br/>
                <input name = "option" type="radio" value="B"><span id = "choiceB">Second option here</span><br/>
                <input name = "option" type="radio" value="C"><span id = "choiceC">Third option here</span><br/>
                <input name = "option" type="radio" value="D"><span id = "choiceD">Fourth option here</span><br/>
                <button type = "button" onclick="populateQuestion()">Submit</button>                     
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching an id to your form and an on submit event listener on the form and prevent the default behaviour of the form to keep your form from reloading the page and do your logic there.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the revised code, it works in jsfiddle.net. So, basically you'll need to update the quesIndex before rendering a new question.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>          
        <head>  
                <meta charset="UTF-8">                                              
        </head> 
        <body>  
                <form type="submit" onsubmit = "populateQuestion()">                
                        <h2 id="question">Question goes here</h2>                   
                        <input name = "option" type="radio" value="A"><span id = "choiceA">First option here</span><br/>
                        <input name = "option" type="radio" value="B"><span id = "choiceB">Second option here</span><br/>
                        <input name = "option" type="radio" value="C"><span id = "choiceC">Third option here</span><br/>
                        <input name = "option" type="radio" value="D"><span id = "choiceD">Fourth option here</span><br/>
                        <button type = "submit">Submit</button>                     
                </form>                       
        </body>                                                                     

<script>
var question = document.getElementById("question");
var choiceA = document.getElementById("choiceA");
var choiceB = document.getElementById("choiceB");
var choiceC = document.getElementById("choiceC");
var choiceD = document.getElementById("choiceD");

var quesIndex = 0;
var defQuestions = [
        {
                question : "Q01?",
                choiceA : "A1",
                choiceB : "B1",
                choiceC : "C1",
                choiceD : "D1",
                answer : "A"
        },
        {
                question : "Q02?",
                choiceA : "A2",
                choiceB : "B2",
                choiceC : "C2",
                choiceD : "D2",
                answer : "A"

        },
        {
                question : "Q03?",
                choiceA : "A3",
                choiceB : "B3",
                choiceC : "C3",
                choiceD : "D3",
                answer : "B"

        },
        {
                question : "Q04?",
                choiceA : "A4",
                choiceB : "B4",
                choiceC : "C4",
                choiceD : "D4",
                answer : "B"

        }
];

function renderQuestion() {
        question.innerHTML = defQuestions[quesIndex].question;
        choiceA.innerHTML = defQuestions[quesIndex].choiceA;
        choiceB.innerHTML = defQuestions[quesIndex].choiceB;
        choiceC.innerHTML = defQuestions[quesIndex].choiceC;
        choiceD.innerHTML = defQuestions[quesIndex].choiceD;
}

function populateQuestion() {
        console.log(quesIndex);
        quesIndex += 1;
        renderQuestion();
}

populateQuestion();
</script>
</html>
```